# how to make python write json read and write same file for each cicle

Tags: python, json, pi

i'm writing a script in Python doing a while true cicle, how can I make my script take the same file abc123.json for each cicle and modify some variables in it?

Comment: Please, provide some code you've already tried

Comment: I don't know what "while true cicle" means, but you probably want to load the JSON file into a Python object, make all your modifications, and then dump the result back to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to read a file named abc123.json somewhere on a local hard drive that is accessible via path and modify a value for a key (or more) for that json file, then re-write it.
I'm pasting an example of some code I used a while ago in hopes it helps

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from os import path

def change_json(file_location, data):
    with open(file_location, 'r+') as json_file:
        # I use OrderedDict to keep the same order of key/values in the source file
        json_from_file = json.load(json_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        for key in json_from_file:
            # make modifications here
            json_from_file[key] = data[key]
        print(json_from_file)
        # rewind to top of the file
        json_file.seek(0)
        # sort_keys keeps the same order of the dict keys to put back to the file
        json.dump(json_from_file, json_file, indent=4, sort_keys=False)
        # just in case your new data is smaller than the older
        json_file.truncate()

# File name
file_to_change = 'abc123.json'
# File Path (if file is not in script's current working directory. Note the windows style of paths
path_to_file = 'C:\\test'

# here we build the full file path
file_full_path = path.join(path_to_file, file_to_change)

#Simple json that matches what I want to change in the file
json_data = {'key1': 'value 1'}
while 1:
    change_json(file_full_path, json_data)
    # let's check if we changed that value now
    with open(file_full_path, 'r') as f:
        if 'value 1' in json.load(f)['key1']:
            print('yay')
            break
        else:
            print('nay')
            # do some other stuff
```

Observation: the code above assumes that both your file and the json_data share the same keys. If they dont, your function will need to figure out how to match keys between data structures.